# java mail api : exception thrown saying java.lang.SecurityException: Access to default session denied

Tags: jakarta-mail

when im trying to send a mail using java mail api in my web application , I'm getting this exception.

java.lang.SecurityException: Access to default session denied

the inputs are fron an html page. then it goes to a servlet which eventually calls a java class where the mail logic is written

Answer (score 88):

This error text is associated with a call to `Session.getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator)` where the default instance already has a different authenticator set.

It should work better if you call `Session.getInstance(props, authenticator)` instead of `Session.getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator)` in your code.

Answer (score 10):

I've got the same error, when I launch 2 tests in Webdriver. In secound test i've got "java.lang.SecurityException: Access to default session denied".

When I used method **Session.getInstance** instead **Session.getDefaultInstance** in every test, errors disappeared.